# Why does the implementation of the offsetof() macro require builtin compiler support?

Tags: c++

I just read this on the [cppreference 'offsetof' page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof):

> offsetof cannot be implemented in standard C++ and requires compiler support: [GCC](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/68ec60c4a377b532ec2d265ea542107c36b1d15c/gcc/ginclude/stddef.h#L406), [LLVM](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/release_70/lib/Headers/stddef.h#L120).

That statement struck me as odd because I remember several years ago having to custom-hack an implementation of offsetof() for an early version of an embedded C++ compiler whose own implementation of offsetof() was strangely broken. I went back in my code and found that implementation, which is:

```
#undef offsetof
#define offsetof(type,member) ((size_t)(((ptrdiff_t)(&(((type*)(8))->member)))-8)
```

Which could be rewritten with modern casting as

```
#define offsetof(type,member) (static_cast<size_t>((reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t>(&(((type*)(8))->member)))-8))
```

In a lot of people's example implementations of `offsetof` you see a hypothetical dereference of `0`  (i.e. NULL) which on some compilers produces a warning about dereferencing a NULL pointer, but I avoided that by using the dummy address `8` instead. (I chose 8 because that address is aligned even for objects that require 64-bit alignment; I didn't figure any of our code would ever run on a 128-bit architecture, otherwise I would have used the dummy address 16.)

Anyway, my question:

I don't see why my hacked implementation wouldn't serve as a correct implementation on any platform? Why does cppreference say that "offsetof cannot be implemented in standard C++"?

Comment: Whether you use `nullptr` or `8` you are still performing pointer arithmetic between pointers that don't point to any actual objects. By using `8` you only succeeded in confusing the compiler so that it can't warn you about the mistake. Silencing a warning doesn't mean the underlying problem is solved.

Comment: `(type*)8` does not point at a valid object. This hack is not an improvement over the equally invalid `(type*)0`.

Comment: You have to differentiate about what the specification guarantees to work because it is specified, and about what works because the compiler vendors agreed on that it should/needs to work to allow certain low level coding.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Casting raw byte addresses to any standard-layout type is pretty common in communication protocol processing. If you have a `uint8_t*` to a buffer of bytes you received over a serial stream, you can `reinterpret_cast` any offset within that buffer of bytes as a pointer to any structure type, and access the result as an instance of that structure. This is common practice, and quite safe. The same can be said of dummy addresses, when we don't even care what's at those addresses. In my example, the compiler never even reads from address 8.

Comment: The assertion that `offsetof` "requires compiler support" is wrong. **If** you know that the compiler's behavior when dereferencing a null pointer is innocuous, the typical implementation of `offsetof` does just that. That's not portable, but that's why `offsetof` is in the standard library that ships with the compiler; it can be implemented in a way that "works", knowing how the compiler handles non-conforming code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ....I should mention of course that "quite safe" assumes no alignment issues (i.e. if the struct being accessed has any multibyte members, then the struct is packed).

Comment: @phonetagger Regarding the pointer arithmetic, it is fine because those `uint8_t` belong to an array. Recently the language has begun to allow pointers to bytes to implicitly construct trivial objects. Neither of these facts apply to this `offsetof` implementation. Edit : I think until C++17 this `reinterpet_cast` approach was NOT actually allowed (though a lot of people thought it was) and required a `memcpy` (which the compiler could often optimize out).

Comment: @phonetagger regarding `This is common practice, and quite safe.` in your previous comment.   While it is true that it is used and does work, it is an anachronism from C, and C++ is not required at all do the right thing here as per the standard, that technique is UB.  C++20 added some language support to make this less so, but only implicit lifetime type are allowed which is only a subset of all possible types.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I don't understand what you mean by "...this `reinterpret_cast` approach was NOT actually allowed (...) and required a `memcpy`...". Can you point me to a page that describes what you mean by that?

Comment: offsetof is defined to produce a constant expression. The suggested implementation does a reinterpret cast... which is not allowed in constant expressions. The compiler must be clued in somehow. A builtin is much easier than other voodoo or heuristics.

Comment: @phonetagger I don't think there ever was a passage in the standard that explicitly forbids it, it is forbidden by not being on the list of legal things you can do with the result of `reinterpret_cast`. You can get the address of the byte you want to cast, you can cast it, but you could not dereference the resulting pointer as it didn't actually point to an object of that type. Edit : The workaround was to have an object `T` and `memcpy` starting from the serial byte onto the `T`, which you could then access.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Perhaps therein lies the disconnect: Many people consider the term "dereference" to mean "a pointer to which the star operator was applied", while other people consider the term "dereference" to mean "actually read from or write to the object that the pointer points to". The distinction is really important, but I keep hearing people say that dereferencing a pointer gives UB, and perhaps by the wording of the standard "applying the star operator to an invalid pointer" may be UB, but doing so doesn't by itself cause a read or write to memory. ....

Comment: ...I would imagine that historically, UB caused alarm because of the cases when it resulted in reads or writes to objects in memory that weren't really objects of that type. Clearly if you don't know what your writing to or reading from, you can't guarantee what will happen now or later as a result of it. But if you never actually read from it or write to it, I can't see how that could be UB, even if technically the standard says it's UB. If you fool the compiler into believing that a certain address holds an object of some type, but don't actually read or write to it, that should be safe.

Comment: @phonetagger My comment was in regards to the general approach of using `reinterpret_cast` to read serially received bytes using a standard layout type, which always necessarily dereferences the pointer. For your question, the problem is not strictly with dereferencing the result of the cast.

Comment: @phonetagger Whether or not `*` or `->` necessarily dereferences an objects (for example when you want to just take the result's address) is, as far as I know, still an open language issue : http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232. It's been ambiguous for over 20 years. It applies to your question, but even if it is allowed, it is not what is preventing the implementation from being portable.

Answer (score 2):

The quote:

> offsetof cannot be implemented in standard C++ and requires compiler support: GCC, LLVM.

Should rather say:

> It is not necessarily possible to implement offsetoff using only standard C++ with a standard conforming compiler.

Your question:

> I don't see why my hacked implementation wouldn't serve as a correct implementation on any platform?

Should rather be:

> Can it be implemented on every platform with every compiler in standard C++?

And the answer to that is: no. Your implementation might be fine on some compilers on some platforms, but that does not imply that there exists a implementation that is fine on all compilers on all platforms. And thats what would be required to implement it without "compiler support". Even if your implementation would be fine on all compilers, it would still be possible to write a conforming implementation where it does not yield correct result.

Comment: OK, great. I am eagerly awaiting your explanation of exactly what features of modern C++ would prevent my implementation from working on a class or struct for which `std::is_standard_layout<type>::value` is true.

Comment: @phonetagger I thought that was already clear from the comments, though that restriction to standard layout is new

Comment: @phonetagger Subtraction between integer representation of pointers is not required to produce the number of bytes between them. The only guarantee when casting a pointer to a sufficiently large integer type is you can cast that value back to the original pointer type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux good call.  Too many parentheses.